# Is it possible to add provider in AndroidManifest dynamically?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Wondering if its possible to add `<provider>` element in AndroidManifest from code rather having it specified in static AndroidManifest?

I see that such thing is possible for `<receiver>`, but couldn't find anyway to achieve run-time addition for `<provider>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Wondering if its possible to add element in AndroidManifest from code rather having it specified in static AndroidManifest?

No, sorry. The closest things are:

- Enabling and disabling components (e.g., activities) via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`
- Registering a `BroadcastReceiver` via `registerReceiver()`, as opposed to it having a manifest entry

> Is it possible to add provider in AndroidManifest dynamically?

No, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ! I'm trying to find a solution for my library that contains a ContentProvider in it. I only want to enable this ContentProvider once for very first app installed on device. Every other app using this library should just ContentProvider by first app, and don't activate their own providers. Do you think is that possible at all ?

Comment: @bianca: Unfortunately, Android will refuse to install an app that has a `ContentProvider` with the same authority as another app's provider, even if the to-be-installed app's provider is disabled. So, each provider would need a unique authority. Now, it's conceivable that you could still make that work, using some sort of election protocol (there's examples of this in the networking space), but I haven't spent the time to try to figure out if it will work and if so exactly how.